# Get list of Drives and Directories on a remote machine with SQL Server installed

Tags: sql-server

One of our apps uses SQl Server databases as backend. I am making a utility that allows making the backup of relevant databases using the App's API. 
I noticed that for SQl Server databases that are hosted on server, I need to specify the local path on that server or a UNC path pointing to that server where sufficient rights are provided. Instead I want to get a list of available Drives and Subdirectories on the Windows Server( or remote machine in the domain) in a form view where I should be able to select the local path to save the backups, by providing the name of the machine. I found a link to sample project but its little old and not working for me.

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/17600/MSSQL-MSDE-Server-Folder-Browser?msg=5052896#xx5052896xx

I was wondering if someone can help me in making above code work?

Thanks.

Comment: Sorry, but I'm not sure why you say it doesn't work for you. the 3 procs that they show in the example list what you want doesn't it? Or do you want to do more?

Comment: Hi Many thanks for your reply. I am tried using the machine Name , then the registered SQl Server name etc but I am getting below error, 

 Load Folder List Error
---------------------------
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Just wondering if you had a go at it and whether it works for your or not?

Comment: You are missing the point. Run the procs in sql, see how they work and how to use them, and then you will probably better understand how the code should work, and why the error occur, or alternatively even create your own that will work for your application

Comment: Thanks jacques.. I tried the procs and they work.. Like you mentioned I am planning to use them to create my own..Thanks for your guidance..